# In Rails, how to write a helper function "who_am_i" so that a view or partial can use it to report which file it is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When designing for layout and styling with CSS, it might be useful to add a line in the view or partial:

```
<%= who_am_i %>
```

or if using haml:

```
= who_am_i
```

so that it will print on the webpage

```
this is view/products/_footer.html.haml
```

How can this helper be written?   (or is there one already in Rails?)

(my first try was to use `__FILE__` and do some manipulation with string, and it works well if everything is done inside the view or partial file, but when it moves to helper, then `__FILE__` becomes `helpers/application_helper.rb` so it won't work.  But I'd like to find out possibly better ways to do it)

Comment: You may also be interested in the [noisy_partials](https://github.com/mattgleeson/noisy_partials) plugin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your helper method should be:

```
def who_am_i
  @template.template
end
```

Rails 3

```
def who_am_i
  @_virtual_path
end
```

**Note:**

I tested the solution in Rails 3.0.5 and it works. I am not certain that it will work in all scenarios. Use with caution.

Comment: I am using Rails 3 and `@template` is nil?

Comment: Updated the answer take a look.

Comment: hm... it says `undefined local variable or method _template`

Comment: anyone know how to do it in Rails 3?

Comment: thanks for your answer. @_virtual_path is very close as it prints out products/_test_partial without the .html.haml... the view/ in front probably is not so important and we can just concat it to the front... I just found that @renderer.instance_variable_get(:@template).inspect will give app/views/products/_test_partial.html.haml... and it works for partials but not views, any other ways or better ways to get to this value not using instance_variable_get?